# how to covert csv to a parquet file with a specific version. (parquet-cpp version 1.5.1-SNAPSHOT)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, teradata

I have a python code like this ， it converts csv to parquet file.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
 
df = pd.read_csv('27.csv') 
print(df)
df.to_parquet('27.parquet' )  

da = pd.read_parquet('27.parquet')
metadata = pq.read_metadata('27.parquet')
print(metadata)
print(da.head(10))
```

the result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgrKo.jpg  which  parquet file version too high

want to change version to     **parquet-cpp version 1.5.1-SNAPSHOT**  ( a small version).

**how to do it?  where to set the file version??**

27.CSV  below

```
Temp,Flow,site_no,datetime,Conductance,Precipitation,GageHeight
11.0,16200,09380000,2018-06-27 00:00,669,0.00,9.97
10.9,16000,09380000,2018-06-27 00:15,668,0.00,9.93
10.9,15700,09380000,2018-06-27 00:30,668,0.00,9.88
10.8,15400,09380000,2018-06-27 00:45,672,0.00,9.82
10.8,15100,09380000,2018-06-27 01:00,672,0.00,9.77
10.8,14700,09380000,2018-06-27 01:15,672,0.00,9.68
10.7,14300,09380000,2018-06-27 01:30,673,0.00,9.61
10.7,13900,09380000,2018-06-27 01:45,672,0.00,9.53
10.7,13600,09380000,2018-06-27 02:00,671,0.00,9.46
10.6,13200,09380000,2018-06-27 02:15,672,0.00,9.38
11.0,16200,09380000,2018-06-27 00:00,669,0.00,9.97
10.9,16000,09380000,2018-06-27 00:15,668,0.00,9.93
10.9,15700,09380000,2018-06-27 00:30,668,0.00,9.88
10.8,15400,09380000,2018-06-27 00:45,672,0.00,9.82
10.8,15100,09380000,2018-06-27 01:00,672,0.00,9.77
10.8,14700,09380000,2018-06-27 01:15,672,0.00,9.68
10.7,14300,09380000,2018-06-27 01:30,673,0.00,9.61
10.7,13900,09380000,2018-06-27 01:45,672,0.00,9.53
10.7,14300,09380000,2018-06-27 01:30,673,0.00,9.61
```

---

As I know the parquet format in tera data has some limits.
Directly using the pyarrow.parquet  should have some problem.
How to write a parquet file for tera data to read ? (file format limits have something to do)  **Any one did this before?**

Parquet Format Limitations in Tera Data

1.The READ_NOS table operator does not support Parquet.
However, READ_NOS can be used to view the Parquet schema, using
RETURNTYPE('NOSREAD_PARQUET_SCHEMA'). This is helpful in creating the
foreign table when you do not know the schema of your Parquet data
beforehand.

2.Certain complex data types are not supported, including STRUCT, MAP, LIST,
and ENUM.

3.Because support for the STRUCT data type is not available, nested Parquet
object stores cannot be processed by Native Object Store.

files which I try.

https://ufile.io/f/wi1k9

Comment: Text is highly preferred over images. You can pass keyword parameters to pyarrow in the to_parquet invocation - see the pyarrow doc for options. But note that "created by" Arrow version is not the same thing as Parquet schema / data page version.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Most of DOC lack of picture. This is a big mistake.

Comment: Thanks a  lot.  Fred

Comment: You can pass keyword parameters to pyarrow in the to_parquet invocation - see the pyarrow doc for options.   how to do it?   no   option  like  version to set up .

Comment: Extra keyword args given in [to_parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html)  are passed along to [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html).

Comment: Thanks  a  lot .   I  will  try it.   :)